# App freezes after clicking on UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, freeze

Hopefully this will be a simple fix!

I am adding a UITextField to my app using the following code in the .m file:

```
editTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
editTextField.frame = CGRectMake(0, [self getTopOfTabBar] - 30, practiceScreenWidth, 30);
editTextField.delegate = self;
editTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:editTextField];
```

However, whenever I click on this UITextField, the app then freezes. No bug or error is produced in the log, the app simply stops responding.

For some extra information, here is the interface in the .h file

```
@interface PracticeViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: have you implemented any `UITextfieldDelegate`'s functions?

Comment: So far, no. Only the <UITextfieldDelegate> annotation has been added.

Comment: If freezing is confirmed, I think somewhere an infinite loop is occurring. Are you overriding `viewWillLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: can you show the implementation of the view , hierarchy of your structure , the reason could be withing the layouts or the rendering in the view considering the fact that you have not added ny `UITextfieldDelegate's` Functions

Comment: I implemented an override of viewWillLayoutSubviews just now, both with and without calling the super method, but the app still freezes. An NSLog which I placed within the function also only appears to be called once when the ViewController is loaded, and isn't called at all when I click on the UITextField, which continues to freeze the app after I've clicked on it. A strange case indeed!

Comment: The view hierarchy is pretty simple from what I can tell! The ViewController is presented from a Push segue, and is correctly displayed on the screen with no issue using the [self.view addSubView: editTextField]; call. As you can see, the UITextField is added directly to the ViewController using this line. I also implemented function calls of textFieldShouldBeginEditing: , textFieldShouldEndEditing: , textFieldShouldReturn: , and textFieldDidEndEditing: , but the app still freezes after clicking the UITextField.

Comment: I thought I had found a solution by converting the UITextField from a simple variable to a property, but the freezing bug has in fact reappeared after being gone for a little while. This is a very interesting bug indeed!

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be a xcode 11 issue:
Fully quit the simulator and rerun the app.  If that doesn't work, some have had success by trying the workaround below:

```
Simulator -> Edit -> Automatically Sync Pasteboard
```

This happened to me as well, but only in the simulator, textfields work fine when I build onto a device.

Comment: I'm stuck with this problem for 30 min and try to find what's wrong about my code. Thanks !

Comment: It worked fine only after reseting the simulator. (Simulator -> Device -> Erase all all content and settings)

Answer (score 1):

Alhamdulellah Soulution is find .....

Simulators >> Hardware >> Erase All contents and settings
this is the approach

[image]